# Kohana 3 throwing a fatal error when validating

Tags: php, validation, kohana-3, kohana-auth

Trying to follow the example on the wiki here: [extending model Auth user class](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=extending_the_model_auth_user_class), and I am hitting a fatal error when it goes to validate.

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Validate' not found
```

Any ideas? Here's the piece of code it fails on:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User
  {
    public function validate_create(& $array) 
    {
        // Initialise the validation library and setup some rules       
        $array = Validate::factory($array)
                        ->rules('password', $this->_rules['password'])
                        ->rules('username', $this->_rules['username'])
                        ->rules('email', $this->_rules['email'])
                        ->rules('password_confirm', $this->_rules['password_confirm'])
                        ->filter('username', 'trim')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using 3.1?  `Validate` is now `Validation` and filters have been removed.

Check out **http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/upgrading** and **http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/57374**.